# How to lock vertical scroll view on a line?

Tags: vim

While going back and forward on history of undo/redo, I would like to keep vim screen vertically locked (let's say lock on line 100), is that possible? how?

I mean that line should be fixed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but requires work. Something like...

Make a mapping that will set (and possibly also reset) the lock. Something like `<leader>l` to set the `b:lock_line` variable to the current line. Then use `nnoremap` to change <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to `execute b:lock_line . "zz"` after it does the original binding, if `b:lock_line` is set.

You can't change the operation of built-in commands like `:earlier`, `:later` etc., as Vim does not allow you to redefine them. You can define new commands like `:Earlier` that would do what you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. At anytime, if you want to see the line no. 100, you can type `:100` in the command mode or `100G` to go to the line.

Once you are in line 100, you can type `zz`, `zt`, `zb` to move the cursor to middle of screen, top of screen, bottom of screen respectively.